# performance monitor - getting current downloaded bytes

Tags: c#, performancecounter

I need to monitor all internet traffic and collect how many bytes was downloaded.

Im trying to use performance counter but it doesnt get the current value, instead it shows only 0. It works when i'm using previously set instance name, but when i'm trying to iterate all of them the value doesnt update

```
static PerformanceCounterCategory category = new PerformanceCounterCategory("Network Interface");
String[] instances = category.GetInstanceNames();        
double bytes;       

private void updateCounter()
{
    foreach (string name in instances)
    {
        PerformanceCounter bandwitchCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Network Interface", "Bytes Received/sec", name);

        bytes += bandwitchCounter.NextValue();
        textBox1.Text = bytes.ToString();
    }   
}
```

now when i set the timer off, the instance name changes but not the value

Comment: Personally I'd use `IPv4InterfaceStatistics` instead, there's a `BytesSent` and `BytesReceived` properties, just record and startup then poll and calculate the difference yourself - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ipv4interfacestatistics(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer myself. as OldFart mentioned, by calling new object each time I reset the counter to 0 every time. I managed to handle this by previously creating a list of all instances and iterating them later. Like this:

```
List<PerformanceCounter> instancesList = new List<PerformanceCounter>();
private void InitializeCounter(string[] instances)
{

    foreach(string name in instances)
    {
        instancesList.Add(new PerformanceCounter("Network Interface", "Bytes Received/sec", name));
    }

}
private void updateCounter()
{
    foreach(PerformanceCounter counter in instancesList)
    {
        bytes += Math.Round(counter.NextValue() / 1024, 2);
        textBox1.Text = bytes.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a rate counter.  The first time you read a rate counter (by calling NextValue), it returns 0.  Subsequent reads will calculate the rate since the last time you called NextValue.

Since you create a new PerformanceCounter object each time, NextValue will always return 0.

You might be able to get the information you want by looking at RawValue instead.

Comment: Is there a way of calculating real traffic values out of the raw values? Is it any way realistic? I've tried it and it actually gets some values but they don't seem to make sense, and the counter shows traffic even in disabled interfaces.